# Что означает сообщение "Compile thumb"?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gcc, makefile

Берется пример HelloJNI и меняется makefile (добавляется опция marm для gcc):

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -marm
```

Проект собирается:

```
$ ndk-build
```

При сборке компилятор пишет сообщения:

> Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c

При этом ассемблер показывает 32 битную адресацию.

```
000002dc <Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI>:
 2dc:   e52de004    push    {lr}        ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
 2e0:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12 ; 0xc
 ...
 31c:   00000018    andeq   r0, r0, r8, lsl r0
```

Что это значит?

Answer (score 2):

Процессоры архитектуры ARM поддерживают несколько наборов инструкций. Один из таких наборов - thumb. Инструкции в этом режиме получаются короче (компактнее), но имеют ограничения на относительную адресацию. Компилятор просто сообщает, что генерирует код именно для этого набора инструкций.

Comment: Это-то и непонятно. Опция marm говорит о том, что надо компилировать в 32-битные инструкции. Ассемблерный листинг подтверждает, что скомпилировалось в 32 бита. Но сам компилятор во время сборки говорит о том, что собирает в 16 бит (thumb). Как же так?